# Best way to implement multiple Alert Dialogs in an Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-alertdialog

- I have an `Activity` with 3 `Fragments`, now each fragment has 2 `ToggleButtons`(total six buttons).
- An `AlertDialog` is shown to the user on each button click.
- Each button does some different action and so the layouts/views of Alert Dialog differ from each other, and so the positive button click for dialogs too differ, while the negative button click are almost same.

I have implemented the logic in an onButtonPressed method in the Activity as

```
onButtonPressed(View v){

    switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.button1:
        // create and show an AlertDialog
    break;
    }
    case R.id.button2:
        // create and show an AlertDialog
    break;
    }
    case R.id.button3:
        // create and show an AlertDialog
    break;
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

This leads to lots of repetitive lines of code, which isn't the best thing AFAIK. I was willing to know if I should keep current implemention, or create a wrapper class something for creating and showing AlertDialogs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modern approach to creating `AlertDialog`s is actually to wrap them inside `DialogFragment`s, so you need to create a class extending `DialogFragment`, override its `onCreateDialog()` method and return an instance of `AlertDialog` from it. For the purpose of customizing the dialogs you can add a `newInstance()` method to your `DialogFragment` as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245408/best-practice-for-instantiating-a-new-android-fragment) discussion and pass custom parameters to your class.

Comment: Cool! If eventually you'll find this answer helpful, please don't forget to accept it.

Comment: Thankyou, I know the rules, Accept the answer if it helped :)

Answer (score 10):

You can create a class and then extend `DialogFragment` class and then override its `OnCreateDialog()` method, then you create a static method to create an instance and pass arguments.

The `OnCreateDialog`

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    //set title,message or view ....

    // when you done
    return dialog.create();
}
```

The static method to put arguments ( [Static Factory Pattern Design](http://www.oodesign.com/factory-pattern.html) )

```
public static CustomAlertDialog newInstance(String title,String message) {
CustomAlertDialog customAD = new CustomAlertDialog();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putString("title", title);
args.putString("message", message);
customAD.setArguments(args);
return customAD;
}
```

Then you could use it like this

```
DialogFragment dialog = CustomAlertDialog.newInstance("titulo","message");
dialog.show(/* etc.. */ );
```

Comment: I like the solution but what is the advantage over a simple ProgressDialog ?@Luis Alberto

Comment: How would you handle varying positive and negative button presses this way?

Answer (score 1):

In my case I all my activities extend a common base-activity class called `BaseActivity`, where I have two overloads for a method called `showAlertDialog()`:-

```
protected void showAlertDialog(Context context, String title,
                               String msg, DialogButton dialogButton) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setTitle(title);
    builder.setMessage(msg);
    Drawable alertDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.alert);
    alertDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, 32, 32);
    builder.setIcon(alertDrawable);
    if (dialogButton != null) {
        if (dialogButton.equals(DialogButton.YES) || dialogButton.equals(DialogButton.OK)) {
            int textId = dialogButton.equals(DialogButton.YES) ? R.string.yesTxt : R.string.ok;
            builder.setPositiveButton(textId, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int id) {
                }
            });
        } else if (dialogButton.equals(DialogButton.NO))
            builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.noTxt, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int id) {
                    onNegativeButtonClicked(dialogInterface, id);
                }
            });
    }
    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}

protected void showAlertDialog(Context context, String title,
                               String msg, DialogButton dialogButton,
                               DialogButton nxtDialogButton) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setTitle(title);
    builder.setMessage(msg);
    Drawable alertDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.alert);
    alertDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, 32, 32);
    builder.setIcon(alertDrawable);
    if (dialogButton != null && nxtDialogButton != null) {
        if (dialogButton.equals(DialogButton.YES) || dialogButton.equals(DialogButton.OK)) {
            int textId = dialogButton.equals(DialogButton.YES) ? R.string.yesTxt : R.string.ok;
            builder.setPositiveButton(textId, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int id) {
                    onPositiveButtonClicked(dialogInterface, id);
                }
            });
        }
        if (nxtDialogButton.equals(DialogButton.NO))
            builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.noTxt, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int id) {
                    onNegativeButtonClicked(dialogInterface, id);
                }
            });
    }
    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}  
protected void onPositiveButtonClicked(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int id) {
   //Override this to handle positive button press

}

protected void onNegativeButtonClicked(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int id) {
  //Override this to handle negative button press

}
```

where `DialogButton` is defined as :-

```
public enum DialogButton {
OK, YES, NO
```

}

Usage :-

`showAlertDialog(this, "Heading", "A dialog with one button", DialogButton.OK)`

`showAlertDialog(this, "Heading", "A dialog with two button", DialogButton.YES, DialogButton.NO)`

PS : Instead of using `R.string.yesTxt`, I could have done a reverse lookup for string in `DialogButton` enum (thought for some this I didn't realise this at that time).

Comment: Very good implementation. Should be accepted answer. Just a small add : if the base activity is in another package (let's say an SDK library) the access modifier should be public instead of protected.